# Feedback for SQL DB Design

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to design a database for an application where users can submit and take tests.

Here is what I got so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgf7m.png

I'm particularly unsure about the relation between `Test_Testee` and `QuestionAnswer_TesteeAnswer`. I need a way to connect the answers & the questions & the tests, but I'm afraid the solution I came up with is a bit naive.

If you can see anything wrong with my design, or if you would do something different please say so, I'm just looking for some general feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It feels a little off.

The testee should take the test (one or more times) - possibly as shown in test_testee.

for each taking of the test, the testee should have 0 or 1 answers to each question:

this is a link between test_testee and question that includes the given answer... one table.